# algpseudocode without visible EndIf

Tags: indentation, algorithms, algorithmicx

I have the following chunk of code

```
\begin{algorithmic}
\State $\mathit{FlatMask}(c)=0$
\If{$\mathit{Inc1}(c)>0$}
    \State $\mathit{FlatMask}(c)\;+\!\!=2(\mathit{Inc1}(c)-1)$
\EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
```

It displays using the `algpseudocode` package, but I would like that the final printed **End If** not be displayed, just the indentation to be reset.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please, embed the code in a MWE.

Comment: Great space-saver for papers !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a simple method to do this:

```
\algtext*{EndIf}% Remove "end if" text
```

An expanded answer is available [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51295/algpseudocode-without-end-block-text).

Answer (score 2):

In this instance it is easy enough to define a new loop, since they do not require an accompanying ending macro:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\begin{document}
\algloopdefx{NoEndIf}[1]{\textbf{If} #1 \textbf{then}}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State $\mathit{FlatMask}(c)=0$
\NoEndIf{$\mathit{Inc1}(c)>0$}
    \State $\mathit{FlatMask}(c)\;+\!\!=2(\mathit{Inc1}(c)-1)$
\State Some code
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}​
```

In the above example, `\NoEndIF` is the newly-defined "loop" structure.