# algpseudocode without end block text

Tags: algorithmicx

`algpseudocode` lets me write code such as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
\While{$n>3$}
   \If{$m>n$}
      \State ...
      \State ...
   \EndIf
   \If{$m>2$}
      \State ...
   \EndIf
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Yielding results similar to

```
while n>3
   if m>n
       ...
       ...
   end if
   if m>2
       ...
   end if
end while
```

I'd like all of that "end if", "end while", "end procedure" text to disappear and everything to compress upwards such that the result is:

```
while n>3
   if m>n
       ...
       ...
   if m>2
       ...
```

That is, I'd like a Pythonic-style where indentations indicate blocks.

Can `algpseudocode` do this? Or is there another package with similar functionality?

Comment: Adding `\algdef{SE}[WHILE]{While}{EndWhile}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}{}%
\algdef{SE}[IF]{If}{EndIf}[1]{\algorithmicif\ #1\ \algorithmicthen}{}%` will eliminate the text, but leaves a blank line.

Comment: Blank lines are unhappy, @PeterGrill, but thanks!

Comment: @Richard: Was working on fixing that but egreg was faster!!

Comment: But, alas, @PeterGrill, egreg's solution with line numbering on results in unnumbered lines dangling off the bottom of the algorithm.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Instead of (re)defining the way `\While` and `\If` works, you can remove the "end line" text via

```
\algtext*{EndWhile}% Remove "end while" text
\algtext*{EndIf}% Remove "end if" text
```

Here's your MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\algtext*{EndWhile}% Remove "end while" text
\algtext*{EndIf}% Remove "end if" text
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
\While{$n>3$}
   \If{$m>n$}
      \State ...
      \State ...
   \EndIf
   \If{$m>2$}
      \State ...
   \EndIf
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}​
```

Comment: This is so elegant! It would have saved me so much trouble. Thanks!

Comment: Definitely worth it if you declare your own commands. +1.

Answer (score 94):

Using the **noend** option as in

```
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Why is this not upvoted more? This solution is definitely neater than the others...

Comment: Yes, this is the standard practice.

Comment: This gives me a compilation error: `Option clash for package algpseudocode.` and no more info.

Comment: is it possible to locally activate this option for some algorithm and not for others?

Answer (score 11):

You can say

```
\algdef{SxnE}[WHILE]{While}{EndWhile}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}
\algdef{SxnE}[IF]{If}{EndIf}[1]{\algorithmicif\ #1\ \algorithmicthen}
\algdef{cxnE}{IF}{Else}{EndIf}
```

Look for the `\algdef` lines in `algpseudocode.sty` for other constructs to modify.

The flag `SxnE` means that there's a "start line", but no "end line".

Comment: Isn't it `SxNE`? Because in the docs, `xN` means "ending command, with no text for this block" and there is no `xn`.

Comment: @logo_writer I don't remember; on the other hand, this appears to work

Comment: @egreg I can confirm that `SxNE` works too! And indeed, `SxnE` also. I guess it is an undocumented feature.