# Program package confliction

Tags: packages, incompatibility, pseudocode

I want to write pseudo-codes in my survey using `program` package. Since I'm writing in other languages rather than English, I have to alter the names of those environments, like `theorem` and `proof`, etc (these environments are all from `amsthm`). I use the command

```
\renewcommand{\proofname}{XXX}
```

in order to alter the proof name, but after loading the `program` package the name turns back into **Proof** in bold font, instead of *XXX* that I want.

Another confliction happened in the usage of vertical bar. The `program` package use `|variable_name|` in both normal text and math expression, and thus when I write the following equations:

```
\[f|_{\mathsf{ker} A}=g|_{\mathsf{Ker} A}\]
```

where the vertical bar refers to function restriction, it is expalined to be a variable and the compiler claims error:

```
! LaTeX Error: \mathsf allowed only in math mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.208     \[f|_{\mathsf
                       {ker} A}=g|_{\mathsf{Ker} A}\]
```

How can I resolve these problems? I know that `algorithmicx` or some similar packages are also able to do the pseudo-code job, but I really dislike their strict **end** or **end if** fashions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider reading [`algpseudocode` without end block text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51295/5764).

Comment: You give no mention of what theorem-related package you're using.

Comment: @Werner I edited it. And thanks for the alternative solution, and I prefer to see whether there is a solution under the `program` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [`program`](http://ctan.org/pkg/program) redefined `\proof` without considering its previous definition. As such, you're better of storing its original definition (made by [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm)), then load `program` and restore the original definition of `\proof`.

   ```
   \usepackage{amsthm,letltxmacro}
   \LetLtxMacro\oldproof\proof% Store \proof
   \usepackage{program}
   \LetLtxMacro\proof\oldproof% Restore \proof
   ```

   Note the use of [`letltxmacro`](http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro) since `\proof` actually takes an optional argument. See [When to use `\LetLtxMacro`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88001/5764)
2. `program` provides `\normalbaroutside` to restore the original `\catcode` of `|` rather than let it be active "in a different way". Alternatively, use `\vert`.

Here is a complete minimal example showing the above discussion:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\oldproof\proof% Store \proof
\usepackage{program}
\LetLtxMacro\proof\oldproof% Restore \proof
\begin{document}
|variable_name|

\[f\vert_{\mathsf{ker} A} = g\vert_{\mathsf{Ker} A}\]

\[\normalbaroutside
f|_{\mathsf{ker} A} = g|_{\mathsf{Ker} A}\]
\end{document}
```