# How to insert end for in my pseudo algorithm and to make it more space friendly?

Tags: spacing, algorithms, algorithmicx

This is my pseudo algorithm:

```
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{Generate Disseminated Sequences}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Function{output}{$memory,input$}
    \State $\text{initialize}~ B \gets  \text{all zeros}$
    \For{$i = 1$ to ${sizeIn}$\text{+1}} 
    \State $\text{return}~OUTPUT\gets \text{convert \textit{B} to decimal }$
    \For{$j = memorySize$ to $2$}
    \State $M[j+1] \gets M[j]$ 
    \EndFor
    \State $B[i] \gets inputString[i]$ 
    \EndFor
    \EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

My issue is

1. I am not getting end For when I run it.
2. I want to reduce the space that it takes but when I put `\vspace` after `\end{algorithmic}` or `\end{algorithm}` my last line come out of those algorithm space.

Comment: Are you loading the package with `noend` or using `\algtext*` anywhere? See [`algpseudocode` without end block text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51295/5764).

Comment: thanks that work, it was \usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably use

```
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
```

This removes all end-clauses from structures. See [`algpseudocode` without end block text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51295/5764). Remove the `noend` option to restore the end-clauses.

---

The `algorithmic` environment is defines as a list. The space afterwards can be adjusted using an [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patch:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode,etoolbox}

\begin{document}

Something above \verb|algorithmic|.

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \State First state
  \State Second state
  \State Third state
  \State Last state
\end{algorithmic}

Something below \verb|algorithmic|.

\hrulefill

\AfterEndEnvironment{algorithmic}{\vspace{50pt}}

Something above \verb|algorithmic|.

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \State First state
  \State Second state
  \State Third state
  \State Last state
\end{algorithmic}

Something below \verb|algorithmic|.

\end{document}
```

It is, however, more typical for people to use the `algorithmic` environment within an `algorithm`, which is a floating block. In that regard, see [Remove space after figure and before text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60477/5764) to change any of the parameters related to spacing around floats.

Specifically, you may be interested in adjusting the lengths `\textfloatsep` or `\intextsep`.