# Alignment of line numbers

Tags: horizontal-alignment, algorithm2e, algpseudocode

I am brand new to LaTeX, and am trying to create a short pseudo code section for a paper. The current issue I'm facing is that line numbers (and vertical alignment in general) is off for many lines.

Here is the code I currently have (I am using Texmaker on Linux for compiling).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[linesnumbered, ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
{\SetAlgoNoLine
\begin{algorithm}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\caption{Leak Detection}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Require{Set $C$ of all observations of interest}
\Ensure{Set $leaks$ of all identified $CH_{4}$ leak polygons}
\State $ $
\ForEach{record $c_{i}$ in $C$}{
\State $\textit{movingAvg} \gets \textit{avg. $CH_{4}$ for past 2 
    min.}$
\State $\textit{movingSD} \gets \textit{SD of $CH_{4}$ for past 2 
    min.}$
\State $\textit{movingThreshold} \gets \max(1 SD > movingAvg, 10\% > 
    movingAvg)$


    \If {$CH_{4} level of c_{i} > movingThreshold$}{
    \State $\textit{flag $c_{i}$ as elevated}$
    \State $\textit{buffer $c_{i}$ location with 20m radius}$
    }
}
\State $leaks \gets \textit{merge of all intersecting $c_{i}$ 
    buffers}$
\State $ $
\ForEach{Polygon $p \in leaks$}{
    \State $\textit{mark centroid of p}$
}
\Return $leaks$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}}
\end{document}
```

And the output looks like this:

[image]

I cannot figure out why none of the lines in the foreach sections are not indented,and also why the line numbers are not cleanly lined up with each other.

I am trying to get lines 2-6 indented inside the first foreach, and line 9 indented within the second foreach. The final return statement is not supposed to be indented, but it is. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

You're actually mixing the notations of [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) and [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx). Since the larger portion of your algorithm follows the `algorithmicx` methodology (and macros), the following is an update of your setup that provides the output you desire:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicforeach}{\textbf{foreach}}
\newcommand{\var}{\texttt}
\algdef{SE}[FOREACH]{ForEach}{EndForEach}[1]{\algorithmicforeach\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicforeach}%
\algtext*{EndForEach}
\newcommand{\AlgBlankLine}{\par\medskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Leak Detection}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require{Set $C$ of all observations of interest}
    \Ensure{Set $\var{leaks}$ of all identified $CH_4$ leak polygons}
    \AlgBlankLine
    \ForEach{record $c_i$ in $C$}
      \State $\var{movingAvg} \gets \text{avg.\ $CH_4$ for past 2 min.}$
      \State $\var{movingSD} \gets \text{SD of $CH_4$ for past 2 min.}$
      \State $\var{movingThreshold} \gets \max(1 SD > \var{movingAvg}, 10\% > \var{movingAvg})$
      \If {$CH_4$ level of $c_i > \var{movingThreshold}$}
        \State flag $c_i$ as elevated
        \State buffer $c_i$ location with 20m radius
      \EndIf
    \EndForEach
    \State $\var{leaks} \gets \text{merge of all intersecting $c_i$ buffers}$
    \AlgBlankLine
    \ForEach{Polygon $p \in \var{leaks}$}
      \State mark centroid of~$p$
    \EndForEach
    \State \Return $\var{leaks}$
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Here are my suggested changes:

- `algorithm2e` uses a `\For{<condition>}{<body>}` approach, while `algorithmicx` uses `\For{<condition>} <body> \EndFor` approach.
- `algorithmicx` doesn't have `\ForEach` defined by default.
- `\Return` under `algorithmicx` doesn't set a new `\State`, so that has to be added manually.
- Non-standard blocks require `\algtext*` to [remove the ends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51295/5764).
- Create a macro for defining `\var`iables; you can always change the formatting later, but it avoid you having something like `movingSD` being considered as the multiplication of math "constants" `m`, `o`, `v`, `i`, `n`, `g`, `S` and `D`.