# Which algorithm packages can I use for indentation based (python like) display?

Tags: formatting, algorithms

I see a few papers such as [this](https://www.jiliac.com/files/ankou-icse2020.pdf) 
[image]
and [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.07147.pdf)
[image]
 that uses an indentation based display.  Note that they do not have an `endif` or an `endwhile`. What algorithm package is being used here? Or how do I get a similar effect?

Comment: Related (and possibly duplicate): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51295/254823

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a starting point, using [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,amsmath}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon

% Define pseudocode formatting
\renewcommand{\KwSty}[1]{\textnormal{\textcolor{blue!90!black}{\ttfamily\bfseries #1}}\unskip}
\renewcommand{\ArgSty}[1]{\textnormal{\ttfamily #1}\unskip}
\SetKwComment{Comment}{\color{green!50!black}// }{}
\renewcommand{\CommentSty}[1]{\textnormal{\ttfamily\color{green!50!black}#1}\unskip}
\newcommand{\assign}{\leftarrow}
\newcommand{\var}{\texttt}
\newcommand{\FuncCall}[2]{\texttt{\bfseries #1(#2)}}
\SetKwProg{Function}{function}{}{}
\renewcommand{\ProgSty}[1]{\texttt{\bfseries #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Dynamic PCA}
  \Comment{$\theta_{\mathrm{exp}}$ is globally given, and initially set to $\infty$.}
  \Function{ExpandBasisIfInteresting($B$, $\Sigma$, $\vec{x}$)}{
    \If{$\var{loss} > \theta_{\mathrm{exp}}$}{
      $\var{loss} \assign \sqrt{\lVert \vec{x} \rVert^2 - \lVert \vec{x}^T B \rVert^2}$
        \Comment{By Pythagoras}
      $B, \Sigma \assign \FuncCall{Append}{$B$, $\Sigma$, $\vec{x}$}$\;
      $B \assign \FuncCall{GramSchmidt}{$B$}$\;
    }
    $\theta_{\mathrm{exp}} \assign \FuncCall{UpdateLoss}{$\theta_{\mathrm{exp}}$, \var{loss}}$\;
    \Return{$B$, $\Sigma$}\;
  }
  \Function{PeriodicDecompose($B$, $\Sigma$)}{
    \If{\FuncCall{IsOneMinutePassed}{}}{
      $B, \Sigma \assign \FuncCall{PCA}{$B$, $\Sigma$}$\;
    }
    \Return{$B$, $\Sigma$}\;
  }
  \Comment{The main function}
  \Function{DynPCA($B$, $\Sigma$, $\vec{x}$, $s$)}{
    $B, \Sigma \assign \FuncCall{ExpandBasisIfInteresting}{$B$, $\Sigma$, $\vec{x}$}$\;
    $\Sigma \assign \FuncCall{UpdateCovMatrix}{$B$, $\Sigma$, $\vec{x}$, $s$}$\;
    $B', \Sigma' \assign \FuncCall{PeriodicDecompose}{$B$, $\Sigma$}$\;
    \Return{$B'$, $\Sigma'$}
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm2e package offers the above (not by default, but it is quite customizable).

Comment: Maybe you could add a link to the [documentation](https://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf) and a minimal example to make this answer more useful.

Comment: @vonbrand any chance for a minimal example?